# How Infinadeck Omnidirectional Treadmill works

Tags: mechanisms

I have seen [this paper](https://conferences.computer.org/vr-tvcg/2020/pdfs/VR2020-2f8MzUJjtCXG6Ue9RYFSN2/560800a382/560800a382.pdf) about the [Omnidirectional Treadmill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnidirectional_treadmill) With CAD model ( with tiny rollers on it):

[image]

Which compered its prototype with [infinadeck](https://infinadeck.com/) as shown below:

[image]

but don't see those  roller in [infinadeck](https://infinadeck.com/) as seen [here](https://youtu.be/GoVAOfU8UJQ):

[image]

So does the rollers in [infinadeck (more zoomed video)](https://www.techspot.com/news/56821-is-this-the-best-omnidirectional-treadmill-for-gaming-yet.html) are so small that can not be seen or that company use another mechanism for this device, for example like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NK41x5kenO4):
[image]

**Update:**

By seeing [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvu5FxKuqdQ&app=desktop) i guess Thanks, infinadeck don't have tiny rollers and only have the chain show in the CAD model of paper like this:

[image]

But i don't know i am right?!

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you assume that the final product put on the market has to be the same as the, or a, prototype? Prototypes are often built to test specific parts or functions and the **results** may drive the form of the final product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinadeck is literally a treadmill made of treadmills. The sideways motion works in the same way as a regular treadmill with belts stretched over rollers and driven by a motor. See https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=fvu5FxKuqdQ for more details